# Python OpenCV and PyGame threading issue

Tags: python, opencv, pygame

I have a python program that starts an OpenCV face detection function on startup. This code works fine and the camera is able to run and face detection works fine. On pressing the 'Q' key within the OpenCV frame, a pygame program (Pong) is started.

However, once the game starts, the OpenCV capture hangs immediately. How do i fix my code so that both are running in parallel?

```
from time import sleep

import cv2
from cvzone.FaceDetectionModule import FaceDetector
import numpy as np
import logging
import threading
from time import sleep
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Font that is used to render the text
font20 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)

# RGB values of standard colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

# Basic parameters of the screen
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
FPS = 30

# Striker class


class Striker:
        # Take the initial position, dimensions, speed and color of the object
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, width, height, speed, color):
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
        # Rect that is used to control the position and collision of the object
        self.geekRect = pygame.Rect(posx, posy, width, height)
        # Object that is blit on the screen
        self.geek = pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.geekRect)

    # Used to display the object on the screen
    def display(self):
        self.geek = pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.geekRect)

    def update(self, yFac):
        self.posy = self.posy + self.speed*yFac

        # Restricting the striker to be below the top surface of the screen
        if self.posy <= 0:
            self.posy = 0
        # Restricting the striker to be above the bottom surface of the screen
        elif self.posy + self.height >= HEIGHT:
            self.posy = HEIGHT-self.height

        # Updating the rect with the new values
        self.geekRect = (self.posx, self.posy, self.width, self.height)

    def displayScore(self, text, score, x, y, color):
        text = font20.render(text+str(score), True, color)
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (x, y)

        screen.blit(text, textRect)

    def getRect(self):
        return self.geekRect

# Ball class


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, radius, speed, color):
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.radius = radius
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
        self.xFac = 1
        self.yFac = -1
        self.ball = pygame.draw.circle(
            screen, self.color, (self.posx, self.posy), self.radius)
        self.firstTime = 1

    def display(self):
        self.ball = pygame.draw.circle(
            screen, self.color, (self.posx, self.posy), self.radius)

    def update(self):
        self.posx += self.speed*self.xFac
        self.posy += self.speed*self.yFac

        # If the ball hits the top or bottom surfaces, 
        # then the sign of yFac is changed and 
        # it results in a reflection
        if self.posy <= 0 or self.posy >= HEIGHT:
            self.yFac *= -1

        if self.posx <= 0 and self.firstTime:
            self.firstTime = 0
            return 1
        elif self.posx >= WIDTH and self.firstTime:
            self.firstTime = 0
            return -1
        else:
            return 0

    def reset(self):
        self.posx = WIDTH//2
        self.posy = HEIGHT//2
        self.xFac *= -1
        self.firstTime = 1

    # Used to reflect the ball along the X-axis
    def hit(self):
        self.xFac *= -1

    def getRect(self):
        return self.ball

# Game Manager

def pong():
    running = True

    # Defining the objects
    geek1 = Striker(20, 0, 10, 100, 10, GREEN)
    geek2 = Striker(WIDTH-30, 0, 10, 100, 10, GREEN)
    ball = Ball(WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2, 7, 7, WHITE)

    listOfGeeks = [geek1, geek2]

    # Initial parameters of the players
    geek1Score, geek2Score = 0, 0
    geek1YFac, geek2YFac = 0, 0

    while running:
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        # Event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    geek2YFac = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    geek2YFac = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    geek1YFac = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    geek1YFac = 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    geek2YFac = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    geek1YFac = 0

        # Collision detection
        for geek in listOfGeeks:
            if pygame.Rect.colliderect(ball.getRect(), geek.getRect()):
                ball.hit()

        # Updating the objects
        geek1.update(geek1YFac)
        geek2.update(geek2YFac)
        point = ball.update()

        # -1 -> Geek_1 has scored
        # +1 -> Geek_2 has scored
        # 0 -> None of them scored
        if point == -1:
            geek1Score += 1
        elif point == 1:
            geek2Score += 1

        # Someone has scored
        # a point and the ball is out of bounds.
        # So, we reset it's position
        if point: 
            ball.reset()

        # Displaying the objects on the screen
        geek1.display()
        geek2.display()
        ball.display()

        # Displaying the scores of the players
        geek1.displayScore("Geek_1 : ", 
                        geek1Score, 100, 20, WHITE)
        geek2.displayScore("Geek_2 : ", 
                        geek2Score, WIDTH-100, 20, WHITE)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS) 

def getface():
    print("Face")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ws, hs = 1280, 720
    cap.set(3, ws)
    cap.set(4, hs)
    fx=0
    

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Camera couldn't Access!!!")
        exit()


    #port = "COM7"
    #board = pyfirmata.Arduino(port)
    #servo_pinX = board.get_pin('d:9:s') #pin 9 Arduino
    #servo_pinY = board.get_pin('d:10:s') #pin 10 Arduino

    detector = FaceDetector()
    #servoPos = [90, 90] # initial servo position

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img, bboxs = detector.findFaces(img, draw=False)

        if bboxs:
            #get the coordinate
            fx, fy = bboxs[0]["center"][0], bboxs[0]["center"][1]
            pos = [fx, fy]

            cv2.circle(img, (fx, fy), 80, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, str(pos), (fx+15, fy-15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2 )
            cv2.line(img, (0, fy), (ws, fy), (0, 0, 0), 2)  # x line
            cv2.line(img, (fx, hs), (fx, 0), (0, 0, 0), 2)  # y line
            cv2.circle(img, (fx, fy), 15, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, "TARGET LOCKED", (850, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3 )

        else:
            cv2.putText(img, "NO TARGET", (880, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (640, 360), 80, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (640, 360), 15, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.line(img, (0, 360), (ws, 360), (0, 0, 0), 2)  # x line
            cv2.line(img, (640, hs), (640, 0), (0, 0, 0), 2)  # y line


        cv2.putText(img, f'Servo X: 1 deg', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, f'Servo Y: 88 deg', (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)

        #servo_pinX.write(servoPos[0])
        #servo_pinY.write(servoPos[1])

        
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
   
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            t1=threading.Thread(target=pong())
            t1.start()
            t1.join()
            #break

    
    cap.release()

def main():
    t2=threading.Thread(target=getface())
    t2.start()
    #t1.start()
    #t2.join()
    #t1.join()
     


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: never mix GUI APIs.